# Something similar to the Acronym module for EE 2?

Tags: add-on

Before I upgraded to EE 2, I used the Acronym module quite a bit on EE 1. Not so much for acronyms, but I used the fact that I could make convenient link shortcuts for frequently reused links with it. For example, I would define the acronym for a particular site as Site A-Link and I would set the text that it would replace to as [Site A](http://sitea.com).

Are there any add-ons for EE 2 that could be used to accomplish something similar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [**Shortcode**](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/shortcode) addon was just released today and may work. I posted the answer below for another SE question but it wasn't what he was looking for. It might do the trick for your scenario so I'm reposting the answer...

> [**Shortcode**](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/shortcode) aims to allow for more dynamic use of content by authors and
>   editors, allowing for injection of reusable bits of content or even
>   whole pieces of functionality into any field in EE. Shortcode provides
>   two types of codes for use in any content in EE: user-defined Macros
>   specific to each author and each site, as well as a simple API for
>   third-party plugins and modules to expose their tags through the
>   shortcode Rich Text Editor dialog (or manual entry in any type of
>   field) - complete with automatically rendered options forms.
>
> **Two Types of Codes**
>
> Macros - User defined, author and site specific bits of reusable content - basically just like Snippets but can they can be embedded
>   directly in any field type by your content Editors!
>
> Shortcodes - Plugin/Module defined tags that can be injected into the middle of content, such as a ProForm form or other piece of
>   functionality. This works similarly to the WordPress Shortcode API.
>
> **Features**
>
> Macros defined by each user for their own use - each author could have the same macros defined with the same names, with different
>   values that are dynamically replaced based on the assigned author of
>   an Entry.
>
> Macros defined by Super Admins for the entire site and usable in all content for each site (MSM compatible with separate sets of Macros
>   for each site).
>
> Macros and Shortcodes can be inserted manually in any fieldtype, or automatically through the included Rich Text Editor tool.
>
> Simple Shortcode API that allows for any Plugin or Module to provide custom Shortcodes complete with automatically generated
>   configuration dialogs
>
> Existing plugins and modules can be converted to shortcodes with very little code. Assistance in the forum is available for anyone who
>   wants to add support to their own add-ons.
>
> Assistance writing glue code for existing plugins or modules is also available - just post a request for support for the plugin in the
>   forum.

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't that be right up global variables or snippets' alley?  You could do that with no need for any add-ons.

An answer to another question pointed out this addon which seems like it may be even closer to what you are trying to accomplish http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/crosslinking